# Azure Function App won't run on Visual studio 2017 Requiring .NET Framework 4.7.1

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, .net-framework-version, azure-functions-runtime

I had my Azure function running by yesterday but after updating windows to Version 17755.1 the app fails to run with n error requesting .NET Framework version 4.7.1 to be installed. I have counterchecked on my pc and actually the .NET Framework version 4.7.1 is installed. I tried to install the it [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-framework-runtime/net472?utm_source=getdotnet&utm_medium=referral) but it won't install.

[image: Error on running app]

[image: Error on trying to install .net framework]

Comment: Which version of VS and Azure Functions CLI are you using?

Comment: Visual studio 2017 version 15.8.1 Azure Functions version 15.8.5023.0 which I reverted from 15.10

Comment: Have you tried to repair your installation of VS?

Comment: Not yet I tried just to install the .net framework sdk from the installer

Comment: I'd suggest to give it a try - if it fails, we can check other options :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That build of Windows appears to have a general issue running any .NET app that targets 4.7.1.

Here is a workaround:

- Go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\[cliversion]\cli`
- Edit func.exe.Config
- Change the supportedRuntime tag to target 4.7.2 instead of 4.7.1

  ```
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  ```

Comment: This needs more upvotes.  Spent two days on this and this immediately fixed the issue.